# How can I select two different string in the word?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have to use word vba to select the different range word.

like:

[image]

I try to use the api: range(start,end).select

but it's only select one range.

Comment: What is wrong with doing it in 2 actions rather then a single action?

Comment: I want to do the action like picture and i don't limit it just one action or two actions.